# Joomla 3.5.1 administrator Error: 0 could not gather sufficient random data

Tags: joomla3.0

I need some help with this site: [www.casalidellaparata.it](http://www.casalidellaparata.it).

The site works well except for his backend: when I'm trying to log into the administrator panel it shows only a blue page without log in and the browser said: `Error: 0 Could not gather sufficient random data.`

I really don't know what to do, on my local machine everything works fine

Thank you so much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat/issues/91#issuecomment-191414036

You need to make sure that your php has enought rights to read /dev/random

Comment: Thank you so much! Have a nice day!